# acumatica approval notification back to originator

Tags: acumatica

I know you can trigger an approval email to the approver of a document when a certain condition is met. However, is it possible to trigger an email back to the originator of the document when the approver makes a decision. Say PO originator gets an email saying the PO is now approved.

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Changes Notification feature. Have a look at http://www.timrodman.com/acumatica-financial-report-change-email-notifications/ for a great tutorial on this.

In your PO case, you would probably only have to set the condition as `Status Equal Approved` and set the email adresses to receive the message.